# Script for hidding outputPanel when pageblock section is collapsed

Tags: visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

Here is what I am trying to do. We have a table which as several rows and columns. This table is placed under a pageBlockSection which is collapsed when the page is loaded using a script.

What I would like to do is have the outputPanel hidden when the pageBlockSection is collapsed and when opened the outputPanel renders. Almost like an extension of the Section but I would like to keep the section out of the as I want to include a check box which shows all the outputPanels if checked. Does anyone know of a script which will determine if the pageBlockSection is collapsed and then render the outputPanel if it is open?

Here is what i have so far inlcuded the script to collapse on page load.

```
<apex:page standardController="Proposal__c" showHeader="true" sidebar="false">
    <apex:variable var="formWidth" value="{!1000}"/>

    <div style="width:{!formWidth}px;">
        <apex:pageBlock id="block1" title="Proposal Development"  >
            <!-- Proposal Information Section -->
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="proposalInformation" title="Proposal Information" columns="1" collapsible="false">
                <apex:form >    
                    <table align="left" border="0" width="400">
                        <tr ><td height="20" width="150" style="font-weight:bold">Account Information</td></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" height="20">Facility : </td>
                            <td>{!Proposal__c.Facility__c}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </apex:form>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <!-- Equipment Section ---------- -->
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="equipmentSection" title="Equipment [$ {!Proposal__c.Equipment_Subtotal__c}]" columns="1" collapsible="true">
                <apex:form >
                    <table align="left" border="1">
                        <tr><td height="20" style="font-weight:bold">Quantity</td></tr>
                        <tr><td width="{!varQuality}px"><apex:inputField styleClass="Quality" value="{!Proposal__c.Qty_Admin_Fee_1__c}"/></td></tr>
                        <tr><td width="{!varQuality}px"><apex:inputField styleClass="Quality" value="{!Proposal__c.Qty_Admin_Fee_1__c}"/></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </apex:form>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <script>twistSection(document.getElementById('{!$Component.block1.equipmentSection}').getElementsByTagName('img')[0])</script>

            <div>
                <apex:outputPanel id="equipmentPanel" layout="columns">
                    <apex:form >
                        <table align="right" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="200" style="font-weight:bold">Equipment Subtotal</td>
                                <td width="100"><apex:outputField value="{!Proposal__c.Extended_Cost_Subtotal__c}"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </apex:form>
                </apex:outputPanel>  
            </div>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        </div>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved via Jquery [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

On load of page run the jquery with toggle as hide

```
$( "#equipmentPanel" ).toggle( false);
```

and then on click of pageblocksection run a jquery script

```
$( "#equipmentSection" ).click(function() {
  $( "#equipmentPanel" ).toggle();
});
```

Please note you will have to load jquery in static resource for this to happen and make sure Id parameter of jquery selector is correct as in my case it can be pseudo as i just used to demonstrate the approach

**Update:**

I went ahead and coded the requirement assuming Account object

```
<apex:page id="page" standardController="Account" showHeader="true" sidebar="false">

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<apex:variable var="formWidth" value="{!1000}"/>

<div style="width:{!formWidth}px;">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Proposal Development" id="blk" >
        <!-- Proposal Information Section -->
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="proposalInformation" title="Proposal Information" columns="1" collapsible="false">
            <apex:form >    
                <table align="left" border="0" width="400">
                    <tr ><td height="20" width="150" style="font-weight:bold">Account Information</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" height="20">Facility : </td>
                        <td>{!Account.Name}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </apex:form>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <!-- Equipment Section ---------- -->
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="equipmentSection" title="Equipment [$ {!Account.Name}]" columns="1" collapsible="true" >
            <apex:form >
                <table align="left" border="1">
                    <tr><td height="20" style="font-weight:bold">Quantity</td></tr>
                    <tr><td width="{!formWidth}px"><apex:inputField styleClass="Quality" value="{!Account.ID}"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td width="{!formWidth}px"><apex:inputField styleClass="Quality" value="{!Account.ID}"/></td></tr>
                </table>
            </apex:form>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

         <script>
         twistSection(document.getElementById('{!$Component.page.blk.equipmentSection}').getElementsByTagName('img')[0]);
         </script>

        <div id="bks">
            <apex:outputPanel id="equipmentPanel" layout="columns" >
                <apex:form >
                    <table align="right" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="200" style="font-weight:bold">Equipment Subtotal</td>
                            <td width="100"><apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </apex:form>
            </apex:outputPanel>  
        </div>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </div>

    <script>

  $( document ).ready(function() {
      $( "#bks" ).toggle(false);
   });
  </script> 

 <script>
   $("img").click(function(){ 
     $( "#bks" ).toggle();
    });
```

Comment: @MonithKumar 
`
<script>function($) {$(document).ready(function() {$( "#equipmentPanel" ).toggle( false) });};</script>
                <script>$("#equipmentSection").click(function() $( "#equipmentPanel" ).toggle();});</script>
`
This was added after the div under the outputPanel and below at the beginning. Looking into the toggle link you sent everything looks right but for some reason not working...

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: what was that?Please let me know if your script not running?

Comment: @MonithKumar still cant get the code to work. I have tried placing in several different locations. See comment above as I believe this is the correct location for the code. Maybe I'm missing a piece?

Comment: @JordanKlepper I have updated my answer and coded myself :).It was fun

Comment: @MonithKumar PERFECT! I didnt think to call the div and not the outputPanel! Just for clarity when you run the script for the click, what is the "img"? It works but I would guess it should be #equipmentSection.

Comment: @JordanKlepper Yes its the Image that we click .Please accept the answer as well if that answered :)

Comment: @MonithKumar Small issue, when a new section and outputPanel is added under this, a copy of everything below the first, all the outputs toggle, not just the one associated with #equipmentSection. I updated the scripts to reference a different '#bks' in your example code. Might this be tied back to the img/click event?

Comment: Keep your panel outside 'bks' div and things should be fine

Comment: They are outside the bks div. A new div, bks1, is created and the script was copied: `<script>$("img").click(function(){$( "#bks1" ).toggle();});` yet when bks is shown bks1 is shown and all the ones below it. Update, with multiple sections the click only effects the sections below the first. So if the first is clicked all below it is effected and if the last is click it only effects that one.